# Convert SVGSVGElement to String

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I've searched for an answer all over but I can't find a way to convert a SVGSVGElement to a string. I'm using Chrome(22). I apologize if this has been answered before but I wasn't able to find it (here or on Google).

I have an SVG (XML) image embedded in an HTML page and am manipulating the SVG with Javascript (adding/removing shapes, etc). My goal is to take the modified SVG XML image in memory and save it to a file (by posting to a php form). The post and php form are working, but the issue I'm currently having is that I can't get the string representation of the modified SVG image.

I've posted a simplified page below where I'm just trying to get the raw XML from the loaded SVG and paste it into the textarea. If you test the html below you'll see that the textarea just contains the string: "**[object SVGSVGElement]**".

I can access each element in the SVG with Javascript and manipulate the elements and attributes, but I can't seem to just get the whole thing into a string. I've tried JQuery and JQuery SVG but wasn't able to get it working. console.log() is able to show the svg/xml, but it's not a string, so I can't seem to store/send it. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

I would even settle for a way to convert any SVG*Element object to a string as I can use the .childNodes[x] property to traverse through all of them, but these are still objects and I can't seem to just get the raw XML.

Test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script>
function startup() {
    svgOutput = document.getElementById("svgCanvas").getSVGDocument().documentElement;    
    console.log(svgOutput);
    document.getElementById("output").value = svgOutput;
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;" onload="startup()">
<textarea id="output"></textarea><br/>
<embed src="svg1.svg"
    id="svgCanvas"
    width="75%" height="75%"
    type="image/svg+xml"
    codebase="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install"
></embed>
</body>
</html>
```

svg1.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
<image id="svgBackground" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="bg1.jpg"/>
<g id="1">
    <text id="shape" x="30" y="30" font-size="16pt" fill="black" visibility="hidden">circle</text>
    <text id="elementName" x="30" y="30" font-size="16pt" fill="black" visibility="hidden">Element 1</text>
    <circle id="circle" cx="12%" cy="34%" r="15" opacity="1" fill="grey" stroke="darkgrey" stroke-width="5px"/>
</g>
<g id="2">
    <text id="shape" x="30" y="30" font-size="16pt" fill="black" visibility="hidden">circle</text>
    <text id="elementName" x="30" y="30" font-size="16pt" fill="black" visibility="hidden">Element 2</text>
    <circle id="circle" cx="21%" cy="63%" r="15" opacity="1" fill="grey" stroke="darkgrey" stroke-width="5px"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer) to convert elements to a string.

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var str = s.serializeToString(documentElement);
```

Comment: I thought that only worked on Mozilla, but it looks like it definitely works for IE9 and Chrome as well. Fair enough then, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

SVG is a DOM element, so you can simply use `outerHTML` attribute of SVG Elements to get the serialized HTML.

```
    var stringData = document.getElementById('my-svg').outerHTML;
```

Comment: More explanation would make it easier for the question asker to understand what you are trying to convey. I would suggest going back an adding additional detail as to why this is the right answer for the question.

Comment: Yes, I hope the explanation is enough

Comment: I got incomplete svg (no text content in tspans) with outerHTML. So it looks like using XMLSerializer is better.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do with jQuery as follows :

```
svgObject  // your SVGSVGElement

svgStringData = $(svgObject).html()  // will convert data of SVGSVGElement Object to string
```

Comment: Internally JQuery just calls innerHTML(), which throws an error when called on SVG objects in IE.

Comment: jQuery is not easier than plain javascript to get the outerHTML.