# how to pass clear html elements(as text format) to backend(express js)

Tags: html, node.js, angular, express, svg

I need to pass an `<svg></svg>` element to backend as clear text using angular HTTP.
 for example, I have an angular-html page with a `<svg>` element,

```html
<div> 
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 540 320">
                <defs>
                <path id="Triangle" d="M120 20 L 220 193.205 L 20 193.205 Z" stroke="red" fill="url(#radial)"/>
                <path id="Maths" d="M250,50C380,50 350,150 480,150" stroke="green" fill="none"/>
                <path id="Chemistry" transform="translate(-200,0) scale(1.5)" d="M250,50C380,50 350,150 480,150" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
                <path id="Path" d="M20,240 C40,280 60,280 200,230 A100 100 0 0 1 300,260 L 330,280 Q 400,320 500,200" stroke="orange" fill="none"/>
                <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0" x2="1" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                    <stop stop-color="green" offset="0"/>
                    <stop stop-color="red" offset="1"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <radialGradient id="radial" cx="0.5" cy="0.6667" r="0.6" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                    <stop stop-color="orange" offset="0.2"/>
                    <stop stop-color="yellow" offset="1"/>
                </radialGradient>
                <pattern id="pattern" width="4" height="4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <rect width="4" height="4"/>
                    <rect width="2" height="2" fill="red"/>
                    <rect x="2" y="2" width="2" height="2" fill="red"/>
                </pattern>
                </defs>
                <rect x="2%" y="2%" width="96%" height="96%" fill="url(#linear)" fill-opacity="0.3" stroke="orange" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="5 2 2 2 5 5"/>
                <use xlink:href="#Triangle"/>
                <use xlink:href="#Maths"/>
                <use xlink:href="#Chemistry"/>
                <use xlink:href="#Path"/>
                <text textLength="600px" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" fill="url(#pattern)">
                <textPath xlink:href="#Triangle" font-size="20" font-family="serif" font-weight="bold" textLength="600px" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">Text adjusted around a triangle</textPath>
                </text>
                <text font-family="sans-serif">
                <textPath xlink:href="#Maths" font-size="30" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle" startOffset="50%">Maths x<tspan font-size="20" baseline-shift="super">2</tspan> + y<tspan font-size="20" baseline-shift="super">2</tspan> = z<tspan font-size="20" baseline-shift="super">2</tspan>!</textPath>
                <textPath xlink:href="#Chemistry" font-size="30" fill="green" text-anchor="middle" startOffset="50%">Chemistry 2H<tspan font-size="20" baseline-shift="sub">2</tspan> + O<tspan font-size="20" baseline-shift="sub">2</tspan> -> 2H<tspan font-size="20" baseline-shift="sub">2</tspan>O</textPath>
                <textPath xlink:href="#Path" font-size="30" fill="purple" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" startOffset="50%">Text centered on a complex path</textPath>
                </text>
            </svg>
    </div>
```

**Is it possible to pass the svg to backend with angular HTTP.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865025/convert-svgsvgelement-to-string/54494195 might be relevant

Comment: Can you post where this svg is generated? Or svg is static or dynamic tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ViewChild` for selecting `svg` element and then by `outerHTML` access the HTML.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t9bxzw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Set reference to `svg` in HTML,**

```html
<svg #svgElement ...
```

**Get data from reference,**

```js
@ViewChild('svgElement', {static: true}) svgElement: ElementRef;

onClick() {
    console.log(this.svgElement.nativeElement.outerHTML)
}
```