# Problem with Convert SVGSVGElement to String

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I need to convert SVGSVGElement to string. I tried all the answers from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865025/convert-svgsvgelement-to-string/54494195)
My problem is that when converted to string, the resulting string lost `<g>` and inside of `<defs>`.

I first generate a squre box (svg), and add some Chinese Characters using HanziWriter ([gitHub site for this open-source project](https://github.com/chanind/hanzi-writer)). Then I console log svg. Next, I convert it to string (`str`) and console log it.

```
    var svg = createSVG(height)

    HanziWriter.create(svg, character, {
    width: height,
    height: height,
    padding: 5,
    strokeColor: '#808080'
    });

    console.log('svg')
    console.log(svg)

    // this way does not work either
    //var s = new XMLSerializer();
    //var str = s.serializeToString(svg);

    var str = svg.outerHTML

    console.log('str')
    console.log(str)
```

The following is `createSVG` function

```
function createSVG (height){

    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.style.width = height;
    svg.style.height = height;
    svg.style.border = '1px solid #808080';
    svg.style.marginRight = '3px';
    svg.style.marginBottom = '3px';
    
    var line1 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
    line1.setAttribute('id','line2');
    line1.setAttribute('x1','0');
    line1.setAttribute('y1',height/2);
    line1.setAttribute('x2',height);
    line1.setAttribute('y2',height/2);
    line1.setAttribute("stroke", "#DDD")
    svg.appendChild(line1);
    var line2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
    line2.setAttribute('id','line2');
    line2.setAttribute('x1',height/2);
    line2.setAttribute('y1','0');
    line2.setAttribute('x2',height/2);
    line2.setAttribute('y2',height);
    line2.setAttribute("stroke", "#DDD")
    svg.appendChild(line2);
    
    return svg
}
```

Since the result is too long, I am showing you in a screen shot, basically `svg` element has `<g>`, but `str` does not. Things inside of `<defs></defs>` are lost too.

[image: result from Dev tool console]

Comment: post the reference of `createSVG()`. Did you try `svg.append()` ?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin, thanks for commenting and asking questions. I added HanziWriter.create I was using and createSVG() function. Any idea?Thanks again!